# How to disable commits for transaction

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, commit

I have a method that pulls information from the database, a large number of calculations, and at the end saves it all to the database. I need to investigate this @Transactional method, run it several times on the prod database (Oracle), but I don't need it to save/commit all results in DB at the end.

One could just comment out the part of the code that is responsible for saving, but there are a lot of such places there, and I don't want to risk running it on the production database.

Is there a way to prevent transactions from making any commits to the database?

Comment: `setRollbackOnly()` (But also you should separate out your calculations from your persistence.)

Comment: Note that even with setRollbackOnly you can still lock records in the production database and you will still put load on the database. Take care.